# How can I find out what type of Network Interface Card my laptop has?

Tags: windows-7, windows

How can I find out what type of Network Interface Card my laptop has? I have a HP windows 7 laptop

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Superuser.

You should be able to **right** click on My Computer and select properties. On the left side click Device Manager. When it opens, click the arrow to the left of Network Adapters. It lists the card(s) installed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click start and type `System Information` Then just visit `Components > Network > Adapter` and you should have all the details of the adapter.

[image]